# How can I remove programmatically-added styles in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, styles

I have a simple paragraph with two buttons which respectively color it and remove the color. The color removal works in Firefox, but not in Chrome (chromium-browser, to be precise). If I were to add the style through a style attribute ( `<p id="paragraph" style="color: #f00;">` ) rather than programmatically ( `$('#paragraph').css('color', '#f00');` or `document.getElementById('paragraph').style.color="#f00";` ), then the color removal would work on both browsers. Unfortunately, this is impossible in my real-world situation. How else can I make this work?

The code looks like this:

**html**

```
<p id="paragraph">TARGET</p>
<input type="button" value="Style me" onclick="styleIt();" />
<input type="button" value="Strip styles" onclick="stripStyles();" />
```

**javascript**

```
function styleIt()
{
    $('#paragraph').css('color', '#f00');
}

function stripStyles()
{
    $('#paragraph').removeAttr("style");
}
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/qBtYW/10/

P.S. I'm pretty sure the problem resides in the way `removeAttr` behaves in different browsers, but I could be wrong.

**edit** I realise I could use css('color', '') but I'm looking for something that will remove all styles, even those I didn't know were there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just set the style attribute equal to an empty string:

```
function stripStyles()
{
  $('#paragraph').attr('style', "");
}
```

I'm not sure why removeAttr is having problems, but I think this should work in all browsers.